# Convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(\log(n+i)-\log n)^2}{n+i}$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Define a sequence $S_n$ of real numbers by $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(\log(n+i)-\log n)^2}{n+i}$ .
Does the $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n$ exist? If so, compute the value of this limit.

I am getting two different answers if I use Cauchy theorem and if i convert this to integral form. Need help.

Attempt:

Let $f_n$ = $n\frac{(\log(n+n)-\log n)^2}{n+n}$ = $\frac{(log2)^2}2$ as n tends to $\infty$
Therefore by Cauchy Theorem $\sum \frac{f_1 + f_2+...+f_n}n$ = $S_n$  and $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n$ = $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n$ =  $\frac{(log2)^2}2$

Comment: Can you tell us what two values you get? And what is the integral you get?

Comment: if I use integral form by converting i/n to x and 1/n to dx I get 1/3(log2)^3 and If i apply cauchy theorem, i get 1/2(log2)^2.

Comment: Your result for Cauchy is what you'd get if the numerator was not squared. Did you perhaps forget the square?

Comment: No, I used the square. Thats how it became (log2)^2 otherwise it would have been just log2

Comment: It's very hard to help you when you figure out what you did wrong when you won't show your work.

Comment: I am very new to Latex usage. I will try to write it out.

Comment: Can you help now @ThomasAndrews

Comment: What do you mean by "log" ? Natural logarithm ? (in this case it's much better to use "\ln")

Comment: Yes it's natural log. Thanks.

Comment: Is it correct what I have done?

Comment: $f_n$ is actually constant, but it bears no relation to your $S_n$. @T.Pal You can never get from $f_n$ to the $n+i$ terms.

Comment: But summation over fn will have a variable i which is present in Sn, fn is the last term and hence I have replaced i with n.

Comment: I don't understand @Ron Gordon why you have deleted your post using Riemann sums because it looks the RIGHT answer ! Numerical experiments validate the result $\dfrac{1}{3}\ln(2)^3$ with an error $\approx 10^{-7}$ for $n=10^{6}$.

Comment: Yes thats the answer I was getting using integral. But @RonGordon has deleted it.

But how to apply Cauchy  theorem here then?

Comment: The sequence looks a lot like it's decreasing, but I haven't proved it. We may bound each $S_n$ above: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(\log(n+i)-\log(n))^2}{n+i} \leq n \frac{(\log(n+n)-\log(n))^2}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} \log(2)^2 < \log(2)^2$$
It is also bounded below by $0$, since every term is a sum of nonnegative things.

Comment: Yes, but that only helps in proving that it is convergent. what would be exact value? How to apply Cauchy theorem there (if we can)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\log(i+n)-\log n = \log\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)$ is non-negative but less than $\frac{i}{n}$, and:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{i^2}{n^2(n+i)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+i}-\frac{n-i}{n^2}\right)=H_{2n}-H_{n-1}-\frac{n+1}{n}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}$$
is convergent to $\log(2)-\frac{1}{2}$. Then, by a Riemann sum argument:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\log^2\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)}{1+\frac{i}{n}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx=\left.\frac{1}{3}\log^3(1+x)\right|_{0}^{1}=\color{red}{\frac{\log^3 2}{3}}.$$

Comment: Thanks. :) I had used Riemann Sum and had got the same answer. Let me know if Cauchy Theorem can or cannot be applied here? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

I can prove $S_n$ is bounded, but for convergence you also need monotonicity (which I believe you have, since going from $n$ to $n+1$ you remove large terms and add smaller terms, so it should be decreasing). Anyways, observe that

$$
S_n \leq \frac{\ln^2 2}{n} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(\ln(2n-1)-\ln n)^2}{n+i}\\
= \frac{\ln^2 2}{n} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(\ln\left(1+1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^2}{n+i}\\
\leq \frac{\ln^2 2}{n} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}{n+i}\\
= \frac{\ln^2 2}{n} + \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(n+i)}
$$

The first part approaches zero, so if we prove the second part is bounded, we're done. Also, notice that the coefficient in front of the sum approaches 1, so the only issue is whether or not this quantity converges

$$
c_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+i} = \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{i} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}
$$

But adding and subtracting $\ln(2n)$ we get

$$
c_n = \sum_{i=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{i} - \ln(2n) - \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i} + \ln(n) + \ln 2 \to \gamma - \gamma + \ln 2 = \ln 2
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Therefore, the upper bound converges, and therefore is bounded. Hence, $S_n$ is bounded.